# Uniform Continuity in Topological Spaces?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, continuity, uniform-continuity

Is it already in literature this generalized notion of uniform continuity in an arbitrary topological space (not necessarily in exactly the same form)? Let $(X, T_{1})$, $(Y, T_{2})$ be topological spaces; let $f: X \to Y$. Then $f$ is called *uniformly continuous-($T_{1}, T_{2}$)* if and only if for every $U \in T_{2}$ there is some $V \in T_{1}$ such that $x,y \in V$ imply $f(x), f(y) \in U$.

In particular, if the codomain is restricted to be $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology, is the corresponding definition existing in literature?

Thanks.

Comment: This is almost the definition in term of uniformities ( entourage form).

Comment: Look up [uniform spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).

Answer (score 7):

The definition you've proposed is a weaker (instead of stronger) form of classical continuity. Indeed, if $f$ is continuous then for an open $U$ put $V:=f^{-1}(U)$ to satisfy your condition.

Now not every function that satisfies your property is continuous. Take

$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x &\text{if }x \neq 0 \\
1 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

With the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ on both sides we have that $f$ satisfies your condition but is not continuous. The point is that we can always choose $V$ to avoid discontinuity at $0$.

There's no way to define uniform continuity on a general topological space. For that you need [some additional structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).