# Is $f$ (uniformly) continuous on $(0, k]$ if and only if $1/f$ is (uniformly) continuous on $[k, +\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

For $f: A \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\}$, is $f$ uniformly continuous on $(0, k]$ if and only if $1/f$ is uniformly continuous on $[k, +\infty)$?

The examples I've tried (e.g. $x \mapsto x^2$) suggest that it is, but I haven't proven it.

If not: Is there a weaker claim that is true?  In particular, is it true for continuity (not necessarily uniform)?

Intuitively, there are many topological properties where $1/0$ behaves like $\infty$, or where $\{1/n\}$ resembles $\mathbb{N}$.  It seems [continuity is topological but uniform continuity is not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3032529/uniform-continuity-in-topological-spaces).

Comment: What a strange question! The properties of $f$ on these two intervals are independent (apart of course the common value at $k$).

Comment: $f(x) = \sqrt{x}\ $ is uniformly continuous, whereas $\ g(x) = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{x}}\ $ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @AnneBauval I've edited to explain the intuition behind viewing $(0, k]$ as similar to $[k, \infty)$, which leads to a potential weakening of the claim.

Comment: It seems you didn't understand my first comment.

Comment: To give an example illustrating @AnneBauval’s comment, we can consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{ if } 0 < x \leq k, \\ \lceil x \rceil & \text{ if } k < x.\end{cases}$$ Clearly $f$ is continuous in $(0,k]$, but $1/f$ is not continuous in $(k, \infty)$. Can you see how they are independent? Without further restrictions on $f$, I can set $f$ to be a piecewise function combining a continuous function with a non-continuous function.

Comment: @VTand Thanks, that clarifies.  I was confusing $1/f$ and $f(1/x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Just consider $f(x) = 1/x$ which is not uniformly continuous on $(0,k]$ but $1/f(x) = x$ definitely is.